# Does anyone know what should i use for validator in AWS AppConfig?

Tags: amazon-web-services, app-config

I am currentluy working on the AppConfig but don't know whether I should use a JSON schema validator or a lambda function as a validator. What is diffrenet between JSON schema and Lambda function? What benefit do they have?

I created a JSON schema and it's easy, but the file is large. I wonder if a lambda function could help and what the lambda function would look like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The AppConfig JSON Schema Validator is a syntactic validation that allows you to check values in the JSON data itself. You can set constraints in your JSON Schema to check a value is not null, a number is within a certain range, a string has certain characters, etc.

The AppConfig Lambda Validator is more of a functional validation. Since Lambda allows you to do execute logic, you can use a Lambda Validator to run a query, do service discovery, or confirm the state of your resources before the new configuration data/feature flag is pushed out/deployed. A Lambda Validator will let you check pretty much anything. You can use a Lambda Validator to confirm syntactically the contents of the data too, but usually JSON Schema is better for that.

N.B.: I work on the AppConfig Team at AWS